# Tomcat catalina.sh starts correctly but starting tomcat.service gives Permission denied

Tags: rhel, systemctl, tomcat

#### Background

On RHEL 8 I have Apache Tomcat v8.5.78 installed under `/opt/tomcat/`.  User & group of the directory is set to `tomcat:tomcat`, so is the directory's content.

I can start Tomcat with

```
$ sudo -u tomcat /opt/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh start
```

Now I try to manage Tomcat via `systemctl`. I have a `tomcat.service` file like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=Tomcat Server
After=syslog.target network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
User=tomcat
Group=tomcat

Environment=JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jre
Environment='JAVA_OPTS=-Djava.awt.headless=true'
Environment=CATALINA_HOME=/opt/tomcat
Environment=CATALINA_BASE=/opt/tomcat
Environment=CATALINA_PID=/opt/tomcat/temp/tomcat.pid
Environment='CATALINA_OPTS=-Xms512M -Xmx2048M'
ExecStart=/opt/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh start
ExecStop=/opt/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh stop

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Note that the service user & group is set to `tomcat` & `tomcat` as well.

#### Problem

When I startup Tomcat via systemctl:

```
$ sudo systemctl start tomcat.service
```

I get "Job for tomcat.service failed...". `systemctl status tomcat.service` shows

```
● tomcat.service - Tomcat Server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/tomcat.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2022-06-22 12:11:59 AEST; 1min 29s ago
  Process: 1641092 ExecStart=/opt/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh start (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
```

and `journalctl -xe` gives:

```
-- Unit tomcat.service has begun starting up.
Jun 22 11:41:47 my.server.local systemd[1638136]: tomcat.service: Failed to execute command: Permission denied
Jun 22 11:41:47 my.server.local systemd[1638136]: tomcat.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /opt/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh: Permission d>-- Subject: Process /opt/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh could not be executed
```

*Why does `systemctl` reports permission problems when the service file specifies the same user with whom manual start up works?*

#### Additional info

##### Tomcat version

The Tomcat version is a requirement - I cannot upgrade to a newer version.

##### What I have tried additionally?

1. Having read https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/498494/45940 I tried in `tomcat.service` the directive `Type=oneshot` -- with no success.
2. Having read https://stackoverflow.com/a/58301082/65889 I tried setting in `tomcat.service` the working directory to `/opt/tomcat/bin` -- with no success

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it was the `.sh` files permissions in the `/bin` directory. They were all missing the `x` (executable) flag.